# Efficient way of adding keys to array

Tags: php, arrays

What is a better way of doing the the below. Is there some function where i can specify/add  keys to my array while splitting

```
<?php
     $str = '2014-02-01';
     $darray = explode('-',$str);
     $final_array = array(
                     'year' => $darray[0],
                     'month' => $darray[1],
                     'day' => $darray[2],
     );
?>
```

Comment: Ideally, you should not do this. Splitting the date string could cause troubles down the road (i.e. when the format changes from `Y-m-d` to, say `d-m-Y`). Use DateTime class to create a DateTime object, and use that to get the year, month, and day.

Comment: @AmalMurali some link or sample code

Comment: Something like: `$date = strtotime($str); $final_array['day'] = date('d', $date);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one:

```
$final_array = array_combine(array('year','month','day'), explode('-',$str));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list()`:

```
$array = array();
list($array['year'], $array['month'], $array['day']) = explode('-', $str);
```